# How to apply font on WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have downloaded 'Bank Gothic Light BT' and wanted to implement it on a WordPress website.

My file is located at `wp-content/themes/alexia/fonts` with the name of `TT0589M_.woff`

This is my code in my CSS file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Bank Gothic Light BT';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Bank Gothic Light BT'), url('fonts/TT0589M_.woff') format('woff');
}

#Subheader .container h1{font-family:'Bank Gothic Light BT';}
```

During inspection of Google Chrome, the h1 do have the property of font-family:'Bank Gothic Light Bt', but the subheader is not rendering the font style, what is the problem?

Comment: You specified style for the h1 inside the #subheader, not the #subheader

Comment: @codingpuss I only want that for h1, but not #subheader =)

Comment: As I see from your rules, the h1 inside #subheader gets that font family. Isn't that what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your theme's stylesheet contains a CSS rule for that element which has a higher *specifity*  than your rule. Use the browser tools to see which rule applies to the element in question, then add a rule to your custom styles whose selector consists of at least as many (and as "heavy") elements than that rule in order to overrule it, for example `.container_all .header #Subheader .wrapper .container h1 { ... }` (That's just made up to demonstrate what I mean, I don't know the structure of your page's HTML)

Comment: Sorry that my sentence not clear enough, the h1 is having the property of font-family:'Bank Gothic Light BT', just that it doesn't render the imported font =(

Comment: and in the local installation the font file is *not* inside a "fonts" folder, but in the same directory as the stylesheet?